# Typescript Definition File custom overload

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to add a custom overload to an existing d.ts file?

I'm using Bluebird Promise.all with and array of 6 items. The definition file covers 5 items:

```
static all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(values: [Bluebird.Thenable<T1> | T1, Bluebird.Thenable<T2> | T2, Bluebird.Thenable<T3> | T3, Bluebird.Thenable<T4> | T4, Bluebird.Thenable<T5> | T5]): Bluebird<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]>;
static all<T1, T2, T3, T4>(values: [Bluebird.Thenable<T1> | T1, Bluebird.Thenable<T2> | T2, Bluebird.Thenable<T3> | T3, Bluebird.Thenable<T4> | T4]): Bluebird<[T1, T2, T3, T4]>;
static all<T1, T2, T3>(values: [Bluebird.Thenable<T1> | T1, Bluebird.Thenable<T2> | T2, Bluebird.Thenable<T3> | T3]): Bluebird<[T1, T2, T3]>;
static all<T1, T2>(values: [Bluebird.Thenable<T1> | T1, Bluebird.Thenable<T2> | T2]): Bluebird<[T1, T2]>;
static all<T1>(values: [Bluebird.Thenable<T1> | T1]): Bluebird<[T1]>;
```

I don't think a pull request is necessary for my single use case and would like to add the definition file so that compilation does not fail when I upload to ElasticBeanstalk.

All I need is the ability to add

```
static all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(values: ...
```

for my project only.

*Alternatively*; can I force Typescript to ignore just this single "error"?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do a declaration merging as far as I can tell.
I'm having the same issue and the only solution I could come up with is to create this type:

```
type TPromiseAll6 = <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(values: [
    Promise.Thenable<T1>,
    Promise.Thenable<T2>,
    Promise.Thenable<T3>,
    Promise.Thenable<T4>,
    Promise.Thenable<T5>,
    Promise.Thenable<T6>
]) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6]>;
```

And your call should look something like this:

```
(Promise.all as TPromiseAll6)([...]);
```

This works with type inference as well.